# Why wont this wp_query exclude certain pages?

Tags: wp-query

I'm using the following wp_query snippet to show all pages on a single page while being able to select individual pages to exclude.

```
// This pulls a list of page ID's from a theme options multicheck field
$pages = of_get_option('exclude_pages' );
// This shows only those ID's that have been checked
$implode_pages = implode(', ',array_keys($pages, 1));
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'post__not_in' => array($implode_pages)
);
$page_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($page_query->have_posts()) : $page_query->the_post();
```

If I simply echo the `$implode_pages` bit in a page it displays like this `12, 31` where 12 and 31 are page ID's

But when I try and include it in the `post__not_in` argument as shown above it only excludes the first ID even though if I hard code `12, 31` in there it excludes both...

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hardcoded `array( 12, 31 )` is *not the same* as `array($implode_pages)`.

The earlier is equivalent to
`array( 0 => 12, 1 => 31 )`

The latter is equivalent to
`array( 0 => '12, 31' )`

`$implode_pages = implode(', ',array_keys($pages, 1));` makes `$implode_pages` a string - which is *not* what you want.
Not only that, it's an entirely redundant step.

```
'post__not_in' => array_keys($pages, 1)
```

should do...

Comment: Your welcome. As an aside, @s_ha_dum's answer does exactly the same. If you accept this, you might care to consider giving that one an upvote. :)

Answer (score 2):

[`post__not_in` takes an array](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameter):

> post__not_in (array) - use post ids. Specify post NOT to retrieve.

Based on your code, `of_get_option` gives you an array with the keys set to the post `ID`s, so what you'd need is:

```
$pages = of_get_option('exclude_pages' );
// This shows only those ID's that have been checked
$implode_pages = array_keys($pages, 1);
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'post__not_in' => $implode_pages,
);
$page_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Codex page for `WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

> post__not_in **(array)** - use post ids. Specify post NOT to retrieve.

So instead of passing in `$implode_pages`, just use the `$pages` array that you get from `of_get_option( 'exclude_pages' )`.

**Edited to add** Whoops, I should have double-checked your question before I posted -- I misread `array( $implode_pages )` as simply `$implode_pages`.

Comment: I can't use the `$pages` array as it outputs like this `Array ( [13] => 1 [7] => 1 [6] => 1 [23] => 0 [12] => 0 )` where items marked with a 1 are checked and those marked with a 0 are not

Comment: Johannes Pille and s_ha_dum are probably closer to the correct answer than I am. My mistake.